# how to change color at "@"positon

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm trying to find how to realize the effect that like twitter,when click **@Xoangle** the **Xoangle** will change color and have a click event.

I searched and someone told me add an UIbutton at @ postion.

but how should I get the exactly postion of @?and I want to know is that right direction that I try to use UIbutton to replace @,can it realize?or there are other ways.

thank you for your time to ask my low level question,highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can have a look at OHAttributedLabel: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel , it can work for you very well .